# Protocol Buffers with Android & Eclipse : NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, eclipse, protocol-buffers, noclassdeffounderror

I want to send some data via an HttpClient and am trying to use Protocol Buffers. 
Descriptor have been created, as well as my .proto file compiled to get the associated .java file. I call this class within my Android classes without any problem and like tutorials & Readme can say. Eclipse doesn't whine about anything.

Now I added all compiled files from the downloaded library (protobuf-2.5.0rc1 and protoc-2.5.0rc1-win32) to a .jar (javac on the whole folder and then tar cvf).

This .jar is now in : libs + AndroidDependencies + ReferencedLibrairies.

The original file sits in the /libs folder.
In the Build Path the protobuf.jar library is set to be exported.

Launching the application works fine, but whenever I try to use my proto builder, here is what I get from DDMS :

```
12-13 13:55:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(12647): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: xxx.xxxx.xxxx.yyy.ProtoObject$Objectmsg
12-13 13:55:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(12647):    at xxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxx.myActivity$Task.doInBackground(myActivity.java:x)
12-13 13:55:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(12647):    at xxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxx.myActivity$Task.doInBackground(myActivity.java:x)
```

Here is my proto file

```
package xxx.xxxx.xxxx.yyy;

option java_outer_classname="ProtoObject";

message Objectmsg {
   required int32 aaa = 1;
   required string bbb = 2;
   required string ccc = 3;
   required string ddd = 4;
   required string eee = 5; 
   repeated string fff = 6;
   repeated string ggg = 7;
   repeated string hhh = 8;
}
```

Code within the Android app

```
import xxx.xxxx.xxxx.yyy.ProtoObject;

...

Objectmsg omsg = ProtoObject.Objectmsg.newBuilder()
                    .setAaa(an Integer)
                    .setBbb(a String)
                    .setCcc(a String)
                    .setDdd(a String)
                    .addAllEee(an arraylist)
                    .addAllFff(an arraylist)
                    .addAllGgg(an arraylist)
                    .build();
```

I really don't see where I could have messed up any library linking. If any of you have an idea about what might be missing, that'd be sweeeeet !

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT ::**

When I take a look at the dexedLibs folder (within /bin) the support library has a real size when protobuf is 1 kB large !

```
android-support-v4-4a44d81301e680a21725a9812ec65b60          132kB
protobuf-d8a49056234d83f3a745e8697859be32          1kB
```

Comment: can you post your code, for better understanding.

Comment: the code is right here already. I can add the call on the builder, but I highly doubt that'll help.

Comment: I think what your posting to server creating a prblm

Comment: Throwing a NoClassDefFoundError ? Humm...

Comment: Not sure about this, but do you need to use 'option java_package = "xxx.xxxx.xxxx.yyy";' in your protocol buffers definition? Or does the protocol buffers 'package' suffice?

Comment: Well the generated .java file is inserted within my own Android app package called "yyy", it's not a side-package.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

Everything was fine from the beginning except that I did not buil the library jar file correctly (Manifest)...

Comment: I think I'm having the same problem, can you tell me how you fixed it in more detail? My lib file in dexedLibs is also 1kb only.

Comment: Well I was building the library by hand, just jaring everything. Using Maven provides a proper archive and its detailed manifest.